# How to get image from resources in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I upload all user files to directory:

```
/resources/app/uploads/
```

I try to get image by full path:

```
http://localhost/resources/app/uploads/e00bdaa62492a320b78b203e2980169c.jpg
```

But I get error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

How can I get image by this path?

Now I try to uplaod file in directory /public/uploads/ in the root:

```
$destinationPath = public_path(sprintf("\\uploads\\%s\\", str_random(8)));
$uploaded = Storage::put($destinationPath. $fileName, file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
```

It gives me error:

```
Impossible to create the root directory
```

Comment: try uploading in public folder.. then you should be able to access with asset() method..

Comment: Okay, how to specify path to public  directory in `Storage::put()`?

Comment: you can use public_path() when saving and asset() when retrieving..

Comment: You mean that: `Storage::put(public_path().'/'.$file)`?

Comment: can you post your code snippet?

Comment: yes, I update question

Comment: Checkout this https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You may try this on your blade file. The images folder is located at the public folder

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('/images/image_name.png')}}" />
```

For later versions of Laravel (5.7 above):

```
<img src = "{{ asset('/images/image_name.png') }}" />
```

Comment: In Laravel 5.7 you an just do `{{ asset('/images/image_name.png') }}`

Comment: @Sl4rtib4rtf4st, yes. will edit my answer to reflect the said alternative on Laravel 5.7

Comment: And also, you may define the asset path by setting ASSET_URL in .env file.

Comment: @Sl4rtib4rtf4st what would be the folder path for such assets? Do I store it in resources?

Comment: @abhig10 still in the public folder

Answer (score 41):

You can make a route specifically for displaying images.

For example:

```php
Route::get('/resources/app/uploads/{filename}', function($filename){
    $path = resource_path() . '/app/uploads/' . $filename;

    if(!File::exists($path)) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Image not found.'], 404);
    }

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
});
```

So now you can go to `localhost/resources/app/uploads/filename.png` and it should display the image.

Comment: Logic should not be placed in the path, it belongs in the controller or the model.

Comment: I tried this approach using Laravel 8 (ex: http://localhost:8000/files-layout-test/backend-layout-header-tb02-03.jpg) and I get ```Not Found``` message. But when I take away the file name extension (ex: http://localhost:8000/files-layout-test/backend-layout-header-tb02-03), goes through, but I need the file extension to be there. Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Answer (score 10):

Try `{{asset('path/to/your/image.jpg')}}` if you want to call it from your blade

**or**

`$url = asset('path/to/your/image.jpg');` if you want it in your controller.

Hope it helps =)

Answer (score 9):

As @alfonz mentioned,
`resource_path()` is correct way to get the resource folder directory.
To get a specific file location, code will be like the following

```
 $path = resource_path() . '/folder1/folder2/filename.extension';
```

Answer (score 1):

First, change your config/filesystems.php

```
'links' => [
        public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
        public_path('resources') => resource_path('images'),
    ],
```

Then normally run

```
 asset('resources/image.png')
```

you will get the file URL.

Answer (score 0):

**Laravel 10 Asset Bundling (Vite)**

if you want to process and version all images stored in `resources/images` you should add the following in your application's  entry point `resources/js/app.js`

```js
import.meta.glob([
  '../images/**',
]);
```

After then reference these assets in blade like that

```
<img src="{{ Vite::asset('resources/images/logo.png') }}">
```

to get it work, need to build `npm run build` or run Vite development server `npm run dev`

For more information https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#blade-processing-static-assets