# How to get the full path of an image in laravel API?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get the path of an image using mutators or helper function for example this is My request :

```
 "placeType": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Kenya Wyman",
        "image_name": "1574668070.png",
        "status": 1,
}
}
```

I want it to appear like this :

```
 "placeType": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Kenya Wyman",
        "image_name": "www.mydomain.com/photos/1574668070.png",
        "status": 1,
}
}
```

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/return-full-image-url-in-api-resource

Comment: $data->image_name = URL::to('/') . '/public/imageFolder/' . $placeType->image_name;

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38736717/how-to-get-image-from-resources-in-laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try This**

```
$user->image_name = url('public/Your path ' . $user->image_name);
```

**OR**

In your Model Add this

```
public function getImageNameAttribute($value)
{

        return public_path($value);
}
```

Comment: yes first solution is in your controller another one is in your model.

Comment: if not work put your controller code here in your question.

Comment: I got this error "Undefined property: App\\Place::$image_name",

Comment: I want to do that in model no in controller

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code :

asset('photos/1574668070.png');

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code :

```
$data->image_name = URL::to('/') . '/public/imageFolder/' . $placeType->image_name;
```