# Get image from resources folder - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Can I get and display an image in view from a resources folder instead of public folder? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`resources` folder should not be used to `store images`
That's not where public, static assets (like images, js, css etc) should be.

Put them inside `public/` folder

The `resources/assets/` directory is for storing `pre-processed` assets, so to speak.

> For example, if you have 3 different CSS files but want to merge them
>   into one and render that new single file in the browser (to increase
>   page load speed). In this scenario, the 3 CSS files will be put
>   somewhere inside resources/assets/.

These files can then be `processed`, and the new merged file will go inside public.

Reference:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/image-assets?page=1

Answer (score 1):

You can make a route specifically for displaying images.

```
Route::get('/resources/app/uploads/{filename}', function($filename){
    $path = resource_path() . '/app/uploads/' . $filename;

    if(!File::exists($path)) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Image not found.'], 404);
    }

    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

    return $response;
});
```

now you can go to localhost/resources/app/uploads/filename.png and it should display the image.
reference [How to get image from resources in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38736717/how-to-get-image-from-resources-in-laravel) 
But again say that resources folder should not be used to store images That's not where public, static assets (like images, js, css etc) should be. as @sehdev says his answer..

Comment: I suggest not to take filename from url, it may subject to directory traversal. https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal

Answer (score 0):

Anwsear to your question is in Laravel's doc: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-app-path

`$path = base_path('resources/path/to/img_dir');`

Answer (score 0):

You can create an symlink:

```
ln -s /path/to/laravel/resources/images /path/to/laravel/public/images
```

Although as other users have already pointed out, the `resource` directory is not intended to be used publicly.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @sehdev.

However, if you still want to serve your image from `resources` directory, here is a solution that gets the job done.

In your view:

```
<img src="/your-image" />
```

In Route:

```
Route::get('/your-image', function ()
{
   $filepath = '/path/to/your/file';

    $file = File::get($filepath);
    $type = File::mimeType($filepath);

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);
    $response->header("Content-Length", File::size($filepath));
    return $response;
})
```

this is not the best solution. I suggest you to move your assets to public directory.

Edit: Use laravel functions. I suggest not to take file path from url because it may subject to [Directory Traversal](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal).